# Altium: How to generate SMD switch footprint using Wizard?

Tags: altium, footprint

Here is excerpt from datasheet for the A6S-4101-H.

[image]

I need two rows of pads. The distance between (center of) pads in a row is 2.54mm. The distance between the (center of pads) two rows is 8.9mm. Each pad size is 1.1mm x 1.5mm. Now I want to use a wizard from Altim to make this footprint but am not sure what option to choose. This package is just called SMD/SMT. But such a "general purpose SMD/SMT" package does not exist in the list in either of the two wizards that exist in Altium.

Comment: Use the SOIC tool.

Comment: I spent sometime and created the footprint manually, it took a while but its done. I will keep this in mind for next time.

Comment: The pin spacing matches a common through-hole DIP pattern very closely - I'd copy a DIP footprint, then change the through-hole pads to surface mount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 3d is important to you (probably is), the best options are either use the SOIC and live with it or improve it.

The pro's of using the IPC compliant footprint generator:

- Quick and easy
- Gives you a black box 3d(still better then none!)
- Creates all the appropriate layer automatically

But it won't (and you might want to correct those):

- Import the proper 3d from a 3rd party website
- Change the silkscreen for something more significant

Side note, many switch definition don't follow the standard pin definition of ic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM3GeQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
So ensure that it fits your schematic!